# Google Game Play Services + Gradle + Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, google-play-services

I would need insight on how to setup the gradle configuration of a libGDX project, I'm working with Eclipse. How to setup gradle files like build.gradle and settings.gradle in order for the the setup to work for IOS and Android libGDX projects.

Thanks to all good help,

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

To add google play services to android open the build.gradle (from the project folder)

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    // ^ default things
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89' // this one, add this line

}
```

}

You will probably need to do the same for iOS. (didn't tested, I don't own a mac).
Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I used this setup https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX. I don't a mac either, order one soon and comment back if the above setup works for the IOS libGDX project also